# Sorting cusom type in Set (Set<MyType>)

Tags: java, set

Why can't I `Collections.sort` my `Set<MyType>`? My code is below. When I use an `ArrayList`this code works perfectly, but when I use any kind of `Set`, I get this error.

```
Set<Auto> set = new HashSet<Auto>();

set.add(auto1);
set.add(auto2);
set.add(auto3);
set.add(auto4);
set.add(auto5);

Collections.sort(set, new Comparator<Auto>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Auto o1, Auto o2) {
        return o1.getMarka().compareTo(o2.getMarka());
    }
});
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code; just post the code as text, indented with 4 spaces so that it is formatted correctly.

Answer (score 1):

`HashSet` is not an ordered collection; in other words, it does not contain elements in a certain order.

You can see a `HashSet` as a bag that contains objects. When you stick your hand in and pull out objects one by one, you don't know in what order you get elements out. You can't sort elements in the bag - because the bag doesn't keep them in the order that you sorted them in.

The order of elements is lost; so sorting a `HashSet` has no effect (besides the fact that `Collections.sort` takes a `List` instead of a `Set` as Mureinik noticed, so your code doesn't even compile).

If you need the elements in the `Set` to be in a specific, defined order, then use a different `Set` implementation, for example `TreeSet`.

Answer (score 0):

`Set`s don't have an order, so you cannot order them. As seen in the Javadoc, [`Collections#sort`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37777862/sorting-cusom-type-in-set-setmytype) receives a `List`, not any `Collection`.